# Flutter: Functions with Argument in Raised Button

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass parameters to Function on Raised Button click. I am using ListView Builder and Raised Button.

```
Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 100,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:5, right: 5, bottom: 5),
            child: CircleAvatar(
               radius: 50,
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xff476cfb),
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.network(
                          lists[index].profilePhoto, 
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                      ),
            ),

          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
              lists[index].name, 
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                     lists[index].baseLocation + ", " + lists[index].country,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.timer,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                     lists[index].registrationDate ,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),

              ],

            ),
          ),
           ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 40.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _unfollow(lists[index].uid),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text(
                      'Unfollow',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                      ),
                  ),  
          )
        ],

      ),
    );
}
```

Problem is my buttons are inactive/disabled (grayed out).

Here is the Function which I am creating.

```
 _unfollow(int unfollowid) { 
     int unFollowid = unfollowid;
     print(unFollowid);
  }
```

I want to get the Id on button click. So, I can perform the async activity. I an open to other ways of handling such scenarios if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing () =>, Please replace below code in RaisedButton

```
onPressed: () => _unfollow(lists[index].uid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onPressed:(){ _unfollow(lists[index].uid)},
```